# Unicorn gets killed due to out of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicorn

Today, I have noticed that unicorn was not running on the production environment. Unicorn error log is as follows (it seems unicorn stopped due to SIGKILL signal):

```
D, [2017-10-11T12:25:49.521336 #9375] DEBUG -- : waiting 16.0s after suspend/hibernation
E, [2017-10-11T12:26:08.051349 #9375] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 9535 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2017-10-11T12:26:21.708135 #9375]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
```

It seeems when the unicorn was killed, we had faced a out of memory problem. In the /var/log/syslog.1 I have following logs:

```
Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309450]  [<ffffffff81190979>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309677] Out of memory: Kill process 9375 (ruby2.3) score 81 or sacrifice child
```

Now my questions are;

1. How I can make sure that unicorn will be restarted automatically even if it gets killed by kernel? (eg, restart automatically after 30secs)
2. In the normal operation, memory utilization is around %50-%60. I would like to understand the root cause and take measures to prevent a similar problem in future. According to the syslog messages, out of memory issue is started with postgres. I have no clue what caused a high memory utilization by postgres or other processes. Any kind of support will be appreciated.

> ```
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309419] postgres invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24200ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309422] postgres cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309427] CPU: 0 PID: 9570 Comm: postgres Not tainted 4.4.0-1031-aws #40-Ubuntu
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309428] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 02/16/2017
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309429]  0000000000000286 08956ec91b465ba3 ffff88000918f9e8 ffffffff813f6ec3
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309432]  ffff88000918fba0 ffff88003cfdb700 ffff88000918fa58 ffffffff81208b3a
> Oct 11 12:26:02 analiz kernel: [4486147.309433]  ffffffff81cc3661 0000000000000000 ffffffff81e667a0 0000000000000206
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you introduce some new functionality that could cause the out of memory problem? For process monitoring you should try something like Monit. But I think you must investigate why the process is being killed.

Comment: after receiving same error few more times, I have upgraded the server capacity which seems to solve the problem right now.. On the other hand, I feel uncomfortable being not able to find the root cause of out of memory issue